# Why that cave dweller is called a misogynist?

Tags: knowledge, perception, history

I was reading [this](https://www.coindesk.com/invented-pants-crypto-creators-identities-dont-matter) article on coindesk.com. The first line of this article says

> "For all we know, the first cave-dweller to rub two sticks together
> was a misogynist. Or maybe just a mean person."

It got me wondering why would you call that cave-dweller or the guy who invented the fire, a misogynist. Is there a logical reason behind this or is there a story behind all of this?

PS: I don't know if this is the correct StackExchange site to ask this question. If it isn't, please comment the other site and I will remove this question.

Comment: I think it is only an example; the point of the author is to assert that: "the identity or character of the creator has little, if any, bearing on the value of the creation."

Comment: The question is not about *logic* and hardly about *history*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA any other tags you would like to suggest?

Comment: "journalism" ?<<<<'

Comment: The author is not speaking about *anthropology*; in the same vain, he may had used as example the [invention of the telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescope#History), amde by a laymen before Galileo. The concept he is stressing is: "the value of the creative result is independent fron the "value" of the creator".

Comment: More specifically, I think that the author think that the cave-dweller was not a proto-feminist...

Comment: You're reading far too closely into this than is needed. The article's title is "Who Invented Pants? Why Crypto Creators' Identities Don't Matter" and the first paragraph says "For all we know, the first cave-dweller to rub two sticks together was a misogynist. Or maybe just a mean person. Even if so, fire is still useful for cooking and warmth." The author is saying that whether or not the first "cave-dweller" who created fire was bad doesn't matter because the invention was still useful. He isn't making any sort of point about misogyny in and of itself.

Comment: Which is explicitly stated a few sentences down: "In other words, the identity or character of the creator has little, if any, bearing on the value of the creation." This has nothing to do with a real accusation of misogyny, there's no story to it, it was a hypothetical example of the titular premise. This question should be closed as 1) it isn't related to philosophy and 2) I believe genuinely is not a substantive question in and of itself.

Answer (score 3):

First, let me kill that idea. Anthropologists do not accept the idea that early humans were cave dwellers. While there have been a few groups of people who did, for the most part, caves are not very hospitable environments. They are dark, cold, and wet. A lot of material was found in caves because neanderthals and early anatomically modern humans used these caves as part of their rituals.

As for how misogynistic early humans were, there is a lot of discourse on this matter. Almost certainly there was a lot of division of labor, but it is complicated to determine how these people lived. We usually look to existing hunter-gatherer societies to give us some insight. I need to look into this [study](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/348/6236/796) more, but it seems to have some useful information related to this topic.

**Ignorance & Headlines**

Now as to why the article in question makes the claims that it does. For one, it is a matter of ignorance. We are still clinging to a lot of false myths about early humans. For another, it fits an agenda. For these articles, the truth is less important than getting a lot of readers. The topic resonates with a lot of people and so, even if it does not match scientific theory and evidence, it is still a "good" article in the sense that it gets readers.

Answer (score 0):

Misogyny seems a conceptually rather complex attitude for such an early human to adopt. Could the early human in question have been a woman or is misogyny exclusively a male phenomenon ? Might the male, if it was a male, have been a misandrist rather than, or even as well as, a misogynist ?

Not the least baffling element in the question is that there is no logical, sociological or anthropological connection between fire-lighting and a sexual or gender attitude of any kind. But I guess the questioner knows that, which adds to the puzzlement.